# New to Ruby on Rails looking for a phone number validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, phone-number

I am new to Ruby on Rails, looking for any suggestions to validate a phone number to be xxx-xxx-xxxx. Appreciate any suggestions. My phone_number column type is a string. Thanks!

Comment: Is it this hard to search in google?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 6):

If you need it to validate phone field in model, you can use this code:

```
validates :phone_number, format: { with: /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/, message: "bad format" }
```

Comment: That is a good way of doing it, but what if i want to do it in the html page itself, like the email_field number_field etc?

Comment: Also, you only care about a specific format here.

Comment: Won't validate some international numbers.